# shared_ptr with incomplete types from library

Tags: c++, sdl, shared-ptr

My problem is straightforward: I am using SDL to create a simple simulation and I want to store instances of TTF_Font type in smart pointers (shared_ptr), but I keep getting this error:

**"invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type '_TTF_Font'"**

Is there any way to use smart pointers with incomplete types from external libraries without incorporating their source code into my program?

EDIT:

**TTF_Font** is declared as

```
typedef struct _TTF_Font TTF_Font;
```

**_TTF_Font** is in turn defined in compiled external library.

My usage of **TTF_Font** is simply just constructing a new stack allocated instance of shared_ptr with a raw pointer to **TTF_Font**:

```
auto font_sp = std::shared_ptr<TTF_Font>(font_p);
```

I don't use **sizeof** explicitly here.

Comment: Please show some code. How are you using the sizeof operator and what is the TTF_Font defined as?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually having a `shared_ptr` of an incomplete type should work. You can declare a function like this

```
typedef struct _TTF_Font TTF_Font;
std::shared_ptr<TTF_Font> makeFont();
```

in a header file without problems. The implementation of `makeFont()` will need to see the full definition of the class `TTF_Font` though. Hence in the implementation file you will need to include the file which defines the `TTF_Font` class. If you want to hide this implementation detail you may consider to put `makeFont()` into a library which you include into you project. This way your project needs not to include the header files defining `TTF_Font` unless you want to access members of this class for other reasons.

**Concerning your Edit:**

When you create a `shared_ptr` from a pointer then the `shared_ptr` will store internally how to delete that object. For this the `shared_ptr` needs to see the destructor of the type pointed to. Therefore, `shared_ptr` needs to see the struct definition even when no constructor is called.

Comment: I'll check your answer when I get home, since I have the project on my desktop. I'll remember you were first ;)

Comment: The typedef doesn't change anything. Keep in mind that I include the header with the same typedef, so it's already there. I tried to supply my own deleter to the shared_ptr constructor and that fixed the error, BUT when I put "delete p;" in that deleter, I got a warning about forward declaration of _TTF_Font class and a note that nor it's destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called. That's not a problem here, since there's a function in that library which in fact deletes the pointer, so I can use it, but in general case I still couldn't delete the pointer.

Comment: That's what I've told you. But it's good that there's a library function which you can use for the custom deleter.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky Hi, can you please say, if I want to add similar functionality regarding `incomplete` types in my homework ptr, what should I do?

Comment: @VMAtm What problem do you want to solve using incomplete types?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky I need to implement sothing similar to shared_ptr (just a homework), and I need to be able to store a pointer to incomplete type without compilation errors. Compile errors should arise only if some operations on pointer are performed.

Comment: This is not the right place to give long answers to questions like that. You might ask a completely new question on the forum. That's what it's there for. Here's a very short answer: `shared_ptr<T>` accomplishes the incomplete type trick by creating an object in the constructor which implements a virtual function from some base class. This function deletes the pointer passed into the constructor and is called in the destructor of the `shared_ptr<T>`. The destructor of `shared_ptr<T>` does not need to see the implementation and can be called by client code without seeing `T`'s definition.

Comment: @PawełMotyl You should move your comment to an answer, this helped me too.